# Joining two different size dataframes, but only want one new column added

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

**If I have df with 3 rows:**

```
 name |    id   |  price
 ---------------------------
  AG  |  102984 | 40
  TY  |  847574 | 90
  RE  |  213441 | 30
```

**and df2 has only 2 rows** (notice they can have same id as df, but not always and every name is BB)

```
 name |    id   |  price
 ---------------------------
  BB  |  102984 | 50
  BB  |  847574 | 60
```

I want to merge or join them into a new dataframe that adds on a column to df1 with the price of BB on df2 --**ON THE CONDITION THAT THE ID's MATCH**
, but leaves everything else in tact.

Desired result:

```
 name |    id   |  price | BBprice
 ---------------------------------
  AG  |  102984 | 40     | 50
  TY  |  847574 | 90     | 60
  RE  |  213441 | 30     | na
```

I tried this, but this just creates _x and _y copies for all the columns:

```
 result=df.merge(df2,how='left',on='id')
```

Comment: You could just rename your `price` column in `df2` to `BBprice`, and drop the `name` column in `df2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this just creates _x and _y copies for all the columns.

This happens when you attempt to merge two dataframes which have 1 or more column names in common, but those columns are not used for the joining condition. The solution would be to just drop those columns, since they're not needed. In summary, you need to

1. Drop the `name` column in `df2`, and
2. Rename the `price` column in `df2` to `BBprice`, since we don't want it to conflict with the `price` column for `df1`.

```
df2 = df2.drop('name', 1).rename(columns={'price' : 'BBprice'})
df2

       id  BBprice
0  102984       50
1  847574       60

df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')

  name      id  price  BBprice
0   AG  102984     40     50.0
1   TY  847574     90     60.0
2   RE  213441     30      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `set_index` and assign it , panda dataframe is index sensitive , when you assign new value , they check the the index match firstly

```
df1=df1.set_index('id')
df2=df2.set_index('id')
df1['BBPrice']=df2.price
df1

       name  price  BBPrice
id                         
102984   AG     40     50.0
847574   TY     90     60.0
213441   RE     30      NaN
df1.reset_index()
Out[150]: 
       id name  price  BBPrice
0  102984   AG     40     50.0
1  847574   TY     90     60.0
2  213441   RE     30      NaN
```

Updated

```
df1.join(df2[['price']].rename(columns={'price':'BBPrice'}),how='left')
Out[163]: 
       name  price  BBPrice
id                         
102984   AG     40     50.0
847574   TY     90     60.0
213441   RE     30      NaN
```

Comment: Only problem I believe( and i shouldve mentioned this), is that all id's are not guaranteed to be unique within df1...(But are unique for df2)